# PHP: Why are some people naming functions with '_' in the beginning?

Tags: php

Why do some people call their functions e.g. '__makethis()' and '_makethat()'?

Is this any special feature or is this just in fashion?

thx for your answers ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The double underscore can sometimes be [magic functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) used by the PHP classes.

The single underscore can be part of their own naming convention for functions. But usually it means that a function is private, back in PHP4 classes didn't support private (or protected) functions, so people fake a private function that way (tho the function is not private in reality).

Answer (score 2):

That's a convention for naming private and protected methods.

Answer (score 2):

Usually private members of a class are prefixed with a '_' sign. Check out the PEAR [code convention](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.naming.php).

[Magic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) methods of a class are prefixed with __ . I suggest if you write a method that performs some magic, prefix it with __ .

Comment: what exactly is the definition of magic?! o.O or make me an example what is meant with magic, please.

Comment: @Florian - for a definition of "magic", look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php